Problem to put two three letters of the hieroglyph package one over the two others
I have this piece of code.
$\begin{tabular}{l}{\pmglyph{n}\\\pmglyph{W}\pmglyph{W}\end{tabular}$
I used a tabular because I didn't succeed in putting the two W hieroglyph letters above the one n letter. The tabular make the letters well positioned but they are too far from each others.
the problem is in the second box of the first line
Thank you for help.

Welcome! Please, add a minimal example of code from \documentclass up to \end{document}.

Here, I use a negative stacking gap of -.55\baselineskip.  This value can be varied, or specified in pt units, etc.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hieroglf,stackengine}
\begin{document}
Like this: 
  \stackon[-.55\baselineskip]{\pmglyph{W}\pmglyph{W}}{\pmglyph{n}}
or
  \stackunder[-\baselineskip]{\pmglyph{W}\pmglyph{W}}{\pmglyph{n}}
\end{document}



Thank you very much, an answer to waking up !
